# GDI throws OutOfMemoryException on loading or cloning bitmap while in an Thread Pool

Tags: c#, .net, gdi

I have a problem where loading or cloning an png file to an .Net (3.5) Bitmap class causes an OutOfMemoryException within the GDI framework.

This code on run inside an ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, at any time the code creates up to 20 calls to the image loading method that has this code.

```
// The GDI may throw an OutOfMemoryException on either load or clone of an bitmap
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
{
    var clone = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size), PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    //post clone bitmap to main thread
}
```

The solution is to put and try catch around the using statement

```
try {
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
    { ... }
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException) { // Swallow the exception}
```

I have tested and shown this defect on Win7 32&64bit machines and Win8 in Normal and safe modes. This defect only shows on 5 out of 8 machines where the tests where carried out. 
Machines are high end Dell and Asus workstations and laptops with different video cards. 
Due to the exception coming from the GDI software stack, I don't believe this defect is related to hardware.
The exception may be thrown less than 0.1% of the time, so rare and random. The files are in good order and are not the cause of the problem.

I am looking for an explanation as to why the GDI throws this exception, so I can explain it to my software team and our customer.

Comment: The System.Drawing namespace actually uses GDI+, not GDI, which does not support hardware acceleration. The graphics card isn't even used. So, the limiting factor here is going to be the amount of RAM on the machine. How big are the file(s) that throw this exception?

Comment: Using that *using* statement you wrote was a nice gesture but quite pointless.  Of course it doesn't work, that would ruin your Clone() call.  So nothing actually gets released.  From there it is an easy memory armageddon, we can't see the rest.

Comment: Are you ever `Dispose`ing of the clone?  `Clone()` creates a copy.

Comment: This is the best explanation that I've seen: [“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx).

Comment: The Clone is Dispose of once the bitmap is copied into an cache. The cache is set to an maximum for 200 images.

Comment: Yes to GDI+ sorry forgot to add the + symbol in the post. 
I can demo this in a tiny test app that I wrote. (If I get time on the weekend I rewrite it and post it up if that is possible)
Thank you for the MSDN link, I don't believe this is the memory problem that I am seeing